# Saving text entries to local storage in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, key, local-storage

I'm new to coding in Javascript and i'm making a mistake when trying to complete a program. My current code is this:

```
function addTextEntry(key, text, isNewEntry) {

    // Create a textarea element to edit the entry
    var textareaElement = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
    textareaElement.rows = 5;
    textareaElement.placeholder = "(new entry)";

    // Set the text within the textarea
    textareaElement.innerText = text;

    // Add a section to the diary containing the textarea
    addSection(key, textareaElement);

    // If this is a new entry (added by the user clicking a button)
    // move the focus to the text area to encourage typing
    if (isNewEntry) {
      textareaElement.focus();
    }

    // TODO: Q1(c)(iii)
    // TODO: Add an event listener to textareaElement to save the text when 
 it changes
    textareaElement.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
      // TODO: Within the listener function...
      // TODO: ...make an item using the text area value
      item = makeItem(
      "text",
      textareaElement.value
    );
      // TODO: ...store the item in local storage using the given key
       localStorage.setItem(key, item);
       });
}
```

As mentioned in the coding comments, my goal is to make and store the item in local storage, however this is not working. I am aware this is very likely a user error due to failing to understand what 'key' I should be referring to in the (localStorage.setItem) line. Apologies if this is a silly mistake or illogical, i'm still learning so I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

My HTML code is as follows and I can add the rest of my Javascript code if necessary:

## My Erehwon Journal rw9438

```
<main>
  <section id="text" class="button">
    <button>Add entry</button>
  </section>
  <section id="image" class="button">
    <button>Add photo</button>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*">
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: *"failing to understand what 'key' I should be referring to"* What key are you currently using?

Answer (score 1):

localStorage can only store a string as its value. You are trying to set the value as an object.

You can either just store the text from your texarea

```
localStorage.setItem(key, textareaElement.value)
```

Or if you really want to store an object you have to stringify it

```
localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item))
```

Dont for get to JSON.parse when you retrieve the 'item" from localStorage

Comment: How would I **get** the newly **setItem**?

Answer (score 0):

no biggie, no mistake it's stupid :)

The key value you are referring to, right now, it's the key parameter from the function: `addTextEntry(key, text, isNewEntry)`.
The `key` naming shouldn't really matter, but for being sure about what it's sotred, you can try add a `console.log(localStorage)` statement just below your `localStorage.setItem`. So you can check what it's stored in your localStorage object and check the key where your value it's stored.

Here an example from the browser console, where the key it's `myKey`:

[image]

Hope this helps.